# Most simple way to connect to dbus signals in a C++ glib application?

Tags: c++, boost, dbus

Is there any way to connect to dbus signals using boost ?
At this time i'm using glib bindings for dbus, but i'm looking for a boost/c++ alternative.

Also, i've found GDBus, which is recommended to use instead dbus-glib.

Answer (score 1):

From the [DBus Bindings](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings) page, there is a link to [dbus-c++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbus-cplusplus/).

Disclaimer: I haven't used these projects and can not vouch for them.

Comment: Without testing the alternatives, the answer is not really helpful.